# Error using effects package in R; wrong variable type

Tags: r, mean

While investigating some fundamentals of multiple regression, I decided to try and compare my manual efforts to those of the "effects" package, by John Fox. I've generated variables with some relationships, and want to get adjusted means for a factor when controlling for the influence of a continuous variable.

I have become stalled, however, as the effect function in the effects package returns an error "invalid type (builtin) for variable 'c'"

When I check the type of variable 'c' using `typeof(c)`, I'm told it is of type double, as I constructed it to be.

- What could be the cause of this error?
- Is the variable 'c' being coerced for some reason to type 'builtin'?

Here is my code:

```
set.seed(1986)
y <- rnorm(100)
f <- sapply(y, function(x) if(x < 0) 1 else 2)
f.f <- as.factor(f)
set.seed(1987)
c <- rnorm(100, 0, .1) + y + f

an3 <- lm(y ~ f.f + c); summary(an3)

ef <- effect("f.f", an3)
```

Comment: As an aside, please avoid the use of `c` as a variable name.  It's an extremely commonly-used [built-in function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14028/3488) in R.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman That was my first thought, but I tried the code with "q" substituted for "c" and the same thing happened.

Still, that is good advice.

Comment: @PeterFlom `q` is also a builtin function :-)

Comment: Slap self on forehead! So, my instinct was right, but I just chose the wrong substitution.

Comment: @PeterFlom I've done it myself many a time!  `q`'s easy to forget since it doesn't really get used as a function, and since it's a more 'mathy' variable like x,y,i,j,p,m,n....

Comment: thanks to you both. stupid me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c` is not a good choice for a a variable name.  It's an extremely commonly-used [built-in function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14028/3488) in R.

Changing `c` to `d` works for me:

```
set.seed(1986)
y <- rnorm(100)
f <- sapply(y, function(x) if(x < 0) 1 else 2)
f.f <- as.factor(f)
set.seed(1987)
d <- rnorm(100, 0, .1) + y + f

an3 <- lm(y ~ f.f + d); summary(an3)

library(effects)
ef <- effect("f.f", an3)
 ef

 f.f effect
f.f
         1          2 
 0.5504214 -0.3231941
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store the data in a `data.frame`; this has other benefits as well, especially if one is working with multiple data sets.

```
set.seed(1986)
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100))
d <- within(d, {
  f <- sapply(y, function(x) if(x < 0) 1 else 2)
  f.f <- as.factor(f)
  set.seed(1987)
  c <- rnorm(100, 0, .1) + y + f
})

library(effects)

an3 <- lm(y ~ f.f + c, data=d); summary(an3)
ef <- effect("f.f", an3)
ef

# f.f effect
# f.f
#          1          2 
#  0.5504214 -0.3231941
```